# WCF Message Contract custom serialization

Tags: c#, wcf

First of all, sorry for my english.

For a 3rd party web service, Visual Studio "Add Service Reference" is generating proxy classes as Message Contract although "Always generate service contracts" is unchecked. For me this is not a problem except because I don't know how to prevent a long field being serialized when its value equals 0.

I've tried creating a Specified field or with method marked as `[OnSerializing]`.

This field in XSD appears as:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="folder" type="xs:long"/>
```

In proxy classes, Visual Studio generates:

```
[MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://foo", Order=1)]
[XmlElementAttribute(Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public long folder;
```

Any idea of how I can prevent it from being serialized when folder=0?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify generated code manually and add nullable data type.

```
[MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://foo", Order=1)]
[XmlElementAttribute(Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public long? folder;
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so easy!!. I'm ashamed. Thank you very much!!